# rspec request test sign in without Devise

Tags: rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to log in a user in my request test, but couldn't get it work. I'm not using Device.

Here's my code

spec/support/spec_test_helper.rb

```
    module SpecTestHelper
      def log_user_in(user)
        post login_path, params: {session: {email: user.email, password: 'password'}}
      end
    end
```

spec/requests/like_a_table_spec.rb

```
    require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe 'LikeATable', type: :request do

      it 'will put table in wish list' do
        log_user_in(create(:user))
        expect(page).to have_content('My profile')
      end
    end
```

And this gives me the error 
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Capybara session methods in request specs where they aren't supported - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec .  You should not be including Capybara::DSL into specs of type 'request'.  You can however include the Capybara::RSpecMatchers if wanted, but you need to call them against a string

```
expect(response.body).to have_content('My profile')
```

The reason for this is that you can't mix the `get/post/put/delete` methods with `page`. `page` and any of the other Capybara::DSL methods are only relevant when you have used `visit` to load the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now as I changed it to feature test, it raised the error undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::LikeATable:0x007fd45a783c10>

Comment: @Rosalie -  Yes, as I stated you can't mix `get/post/put/delete` with Capybara.  Feature tests would use Capybara, so you can't use `post` - the only thing you can use there is `visit`.  To use `post` you would need to be a request spec where you can't use any of the Capybara session methods, actions, finders, etc - only the matchers against strings (response.body)

Comment: ah ok, so does it mean, if I want to simulate a scenario where only a logged in user can do, I have to also first do the log in scenario? (as in to click on log in and fill in the form) or is there a simple way to do the scenario as a logged in user without going through the log in scenario again? Sorry for my stupid questions.  I'm very new to rails or testing

Comment: @Rosalie Unless you implement a shortcut method like Devise does through the Warden middleware with Warden::Test::Helpers ( shown at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara )  then yes you'd need to write a method that clicks on log in and fills in the form and asserts it's completed the login, and then call that method every time (in a before block/hook or similar)